# Split a string(a word) to letters in C

Tags: c

I need a string to split into its letters and save it in an array .I have no clue how to do this .Its possible in C++ but in C it seems like there is no way to do.

Or if there is a way to take an input string(a word )and save it as separate letters in an array will be ideal .I have used below mentioned code to get the input

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int(){
char inputnumber;
        printf(  "Enter the number" ); 
// the word is like --> hellooo
         scanf("%s", &inputnumber);
int i=0;
printf(inputnumber[i]);
    }
```

Update: this is solved ,I did not declare a pointer to the char here ,that's the part which is missing then we can read the word  letter by letter ,thanks all

Comment: A string is really just an *array* of characters, terminated by a special character (`'\0'`). You *do* know how to loop over an array?

Comment: Could you pause and think: "How C++ would have done it? Or, how that api (or method) would have done it?"

Comment: Just declare `inputnumber` as a char array and your mostly done (still need to ensure you don't overflow the array). In C a string is by definition a sequence of characters terminated by the `NUL` (`\0`) byte. So once `scanf` puts the string into the array it already contains the letters the way you want.

Comment: I am asking about a single word ,not a bunch of words .a word (the input is just a single word ) should be separated into its letters like HELLO to H  E  L  L  O and store in an array

Comment: But if you read a word with e.g. `scanf` and store it in an array, it already *is* separated as single characters in an array. You need to elaborate on what your problem is.

Comment: The problem with the code you show after your edit is that `inputnumber` is a *single* character and not an *array* of characters. You *did* read my comments?

Comment: i was reading all the comments ,thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at this code and see your mistakes

```
        #include <stdio.h>
    //  #include <stdlib.h> // you dont really need this
    //  #include <math.h> // or this
    //  #include<string.h> // or this
        //int(){
        int main (){ // <-- int main here
                printf(  "Enter the number" );
                // declare a character array to Store input String
                char inputnumber[126];
                scanf("%s", &inputnumber);

                /** take a pointer to point to first character **/
                char *p = inputnumber;

                /** iterate through it untill you get '\0' - a speial character indicating the end of string */
                while ( *p != '\0' ) {
                       // <- print characters not strings hence c
                      //based on your requirement you can store this in another array
                        printf ("%c ", *p  ); 

                        p++ ; // move p to point to next position
                }

                return 0; // return happyily
        }
```

Comment: you saved my lot of time may be even more than you think ,thanks a lot

Comment: That's a really roundabout way to loop over a string, when e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(inputnumber) /* or inputnumber[i] != '\0' */; ++i)`  would work just as fine and, IMO, be more clearer.

Comment: Also, you might want to limit that `scanf` call to now overflow the array, by using `"%125s"`.

Comment: for someone starting program as int() , IMO the answer will have no value

Comment: I just tried this and worked ,needed this for my project .

Comment: I have done a lot of mistakes here because i was in a hurry ,this answer has everything that i needed