# Checking if two strings contain the same characters regardless of order

Tags: c, arrays, string

Assuming that two strings are equal in length, is there a way to know how many characters they have in common, using C? 
For example, if we enter FABBOL and LABTIF, the program should output 4. If we enter FABBOL and LABBIF, the program should output 5.

Comment: Do you have any code you have done you wish to present?

Comment: Is there a way? Sure. Some tend to think that our brain is Turing-complete. C is Turing-complete. So if you can do it then it can be done with C.

Comment: No, not really. At first i was thinking of comparing each character in the first string, to all characters in the second string, (using a count) but there's the problem of repitition of characters. I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: Can you tell me how please?

Comment: @NadaAlami Try to write down how would *you* do it. Systematically. It will give you the algorithm.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858256/split-a-stringa-word-to-letters-in-c) should help you on how to split the input

Comment: @EugeneSh. The `malloc` function in C standard is allowed to return NULL when no memory can be allocated. This gives me an impression that C implementations can have an upper bound on the maximum memory they can have, which would make them a simple DFA and not Turing complete. Again, that would make the implementation to be not turing complete. I am looking if the standard mentions anything about limits on memory available. I don't know about our brains.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya As I said "Some tend". Including me, but you are free to disagree. Yet there is no proof the brain is going beyond Turing. As for the memory - it can always be extended to accommodate the specific problem needs making it virtually infinite (which is most probably false for the brain, by the way, as we don't know how to extend it, and being a finite physical entity it *must* have a limitation if we are not involving metaphysical and esoteric stuff here).

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you agree that brain has finite memory, then it should not be turing complete.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Well, that's sad, but yes :) Anyway brain+(infinite)piece of paper will do.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah yes, a paper ofcourse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. Here are three:

---

One way would be to emulate what many do (either in their head or on paper) when asked to count the characters by hand. Let's call the strings `s1` and `s2`. It does not matter which is which, you'll get the same result anyway.

```
Set Count = 0
For each character c in s1:
    If s2 contains c:
        Strike out the character in s2
        Set Count = Count + 1
End for
Return Count
```

Note that one of the strings, above `s2`, is modified -- to avoid counting the same character more than once in `s2` if it occurs more than once in `s1`. This usually means you use a temporary copy of `s2`, so that original `s2` does not get destroyed (and can be e.g. a string literal; they cannot be modified). C has a function [`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) that can be used to locate if a string contains a specific character; and a function [`wcschr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wcschr.3.html) if a wide string contains a specific wide character.

Algorithm-wise, this has *O(NM)* time complexity, and *O(N)* space complexity, where *N* and *M* are the lengths of the two strings.

---

For normal (narrow) strings, another way would be to create two arrays of character counts -- that is, arrays of unsigned integers with `CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1` elements --, and count the occurrences of each character. The result is then the sum over all characters, using the smaller count for each character.

If the string lengths are *N* and *M*, and there are *L* possible character, this approach has *O(max(N, M, L))* time complexity, and *O(L)* space complexity.

---

You could sort the characters in each string. The order itself does not matter, as long as it is the same in both.

You start with the first character in each sorted string, and keep an index (a finger!) on one character in each sorted string.  Start with count zero, then:

- If one character is before the other, you skip the earlier character, moving that index (finger) to the next character.
- If one or both indexes (fingers) reaches the end of their respective strings, we are complete; return the count.
- If the indexes in the two sorted strings point to a similar character, you increment the count, and advance both indexes (fingers)

This has a time complexity of *O(max(N log N, M log M))*, because the sort is usually done by a comparison sort, and at best, they have a time complexity of *O(N log N)*. You probably need *O(N + M)* extra space, if you don't want to garble the original strings.

It is possible to use a radix sort to get *O(max(N, M))* time complexity (because there is a strictly finite number of unique characters, and radix sort is not a comparison-based sort), but unless the strings are extremely long, it will be slower than many comparison-based sorts in practice. Besides, radix sorts usually need quite a lot of extra space (exactly how much depends on the implementation).

This is very similar to striking out the characters already considered, except that we first reorder the characters, and "strike" them out by moving the respective index (finger).

Answer (score 1):

Count each character and check it.
like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned number_of_common(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    unsigned count[256] = {0};
    //Make it unsigned for use as subscript.
    const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char*)s1;
    while(*s)
        ++count[*s++];

    unsigned common = 0;
    for(s = (const unsigned char*)s2; *s; ++s){
        if(count[*s]){
            ++common;
            --count[*s];
        }
    }
    return common;
}

int main(void){
    unsigned count[256];
    char string1[256], string2[256];

    printf("input string #1>");fflush(stdout);
    fgets(string1, sizeof string1, stdin);
    string1[strcspn(string1, "\n")] = 0;//chomp newline

    printf("input string #2>");fflush(stdout);
    fgets(string2, sizeof string2, stdin);
    string2[strcspn(string2, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("number of common character is %u\n", number_of_common(string1, string2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We are not a coding service for lazy homeworkers!

Comment: @Olaf OP asked how to do it. You need to present evidence that it is homework.

Comment: Let alone this is a weak excuse, even if it is not homework, we are not a coding service for "the next big thing" either. You really have no need to break site-rules just for few reps.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a bad practice to present the code to show the way. It really helps to show the flow. Even though it actually works, not pseudo code.

Comment: @chux type of `*s` is unsigned type.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY And so it is!

Answer (score -1):

Sort the characters in the strings.  Then ...

Sudocode (c is a read-only language for me these days):

```
int str1Idx = 0;
int str2Idx = 0;
int hitCount = 0;

while ( str1Idx < strlen( string1 ) )
{
    while ( str2Idx < strlen( string2 ) )
    {
        if ( string1[ str1Idx ] == string2[ str2Idx ] )
        {
            ++hitCount;
            ++str2Idx;
            break;
        }

        if ( string1[ str1Idx ] < string2[ str2Idx ] )
        {
            break;
        }

        ++str2Idx;       
    }

    ++str1Idx;
}
```

Obviously, I'm simplifying things as this is c and doing things like sorting and even character comparisons are more work than in more modern languages, but this is the gist of it.

You were on the right track; sort the characters first and the rest should fall into place.

Comment: We are not a coding service for lazy homeworkers!